# Why don't these LESS_TERMCAP variables work on Oracle Linux?

Tags: less, termcap

I've been using these variables for a long time to colourise man pages:

```
# Colourise man pages
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[1;31m'      # begin bold
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[1;36m'      # begin blink
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m'         # reset bold/blink
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[01;44;30m'  # begin reverse video
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m'         # reset reverse video
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[1;32m'      # begin underline
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m'         # reset underline
export LESS_TERMCAP_mr=$(tput rev)
export LESS_TERMCAP_mh=$(tput dim)
export LESS_TERMCAP_ZN=$(tput ssubm)
export LESS_TERMCAP_ZV=$(tput rsubm)
export LESS_TERMCAP_ZO=$(tput ssupm)
export LESS_TERMCAP_ZW=$(tput rsupm)
```

I am considering putting them into a function so that they don't clutter my environment variables (but then they don't work with `git apply --help`, but do with `man git-apply`).

```
# Colourise man pages
man() {
  env \
    LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[1;31m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[1;36m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[01;44;30m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[1;32m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_mr=$(tput rev) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_mh=$(tput dim) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ZN=$(tput ssubm) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ZV=$(tput rsubm) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ZO=$(tput ssupm) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ZW=$(tput rsupm) \
    man "$@"
}
```

Recently I have started using Oracle Linux and they don't work there. Oracle Linux is based on Scientific Linux (I think) so this probably doesn't work on RHEL and variants like CentOS/Fedora etc.

How can I make this work on all types of Linux?

Comment: Does it work if you `man ls | less` (replace `ls` with a page of your choice)?

Comment: @roaima No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an additional setting, either standalone or as part of the function definition:

```
export GROFF_NO_SGR=1
```

Or

```
man() {
  env \
    LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[1;31m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[1;36m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[01;44;30m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[1;32m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_mr=$(tput rev) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_mh=$(tput dim) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ZN=$(tput ssubm) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ZV=$(tput rsubm) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ZO=$(tput ssupm) \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ZW=$(tput rsupm) \
    GROFF_NO_SGR=1 \
    man "$@"
}
```

Reference: [Bug 1028764 - Manual pages are no longer colorized in less by LESS_TERMCAP_*](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1028764)